# Swift で Gemini AI を使いたいが上手く動くかない

Tags: swift, xcode

以下のコードにある `\(location.name)` 、 `\(location.address)` をgemini AIを使って建物について `Text("番号: \(location.phoneNumber)")` の下に表示したいのですが、上手くできませんでした。

xcodeのパッケージで [generative-ai-swift](https://github.com/google/generative-ai-swift) をインストールしてます。
Gemini AIについては以下の記事を参考にしています。

[【初心者向け】iPad だけで Google の AI モデル「Gemini」を使ったアプリを作ってみよう！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/treastrain/items/6ed2802836969d308481)

どなたかこのコードでGemini AIを使って動かせるコードを教えて頂きたいです。
`appid=`はAPIキーになっているのでXで伏せさせてください。

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct LocationInfo {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var coordinates: String
    var locat12: String
    var locat23: String
    var locat25: String
    
    init(name: String, address: String, phoneNumber: String, coordinates: String, locat12: String, locat23: String, locat25: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.locat12 = locat12
        self.locat23 = locat23
        self.locat25 = locat25
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, XMLParserDelegate {
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    var selectedCategory = "0401"
    var locations: [LocationInfo] = []
    var isReadingFeatureName = false
    var shouldSkip = false
    var locat12: String = ""
    var locat23: String = ""
    var locat25: String = ""
    var locat1: String = ""
    var currentCoordinates: String = ""

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var currentElement: String = ""
    var currentiName: String = ""
    var currentAddress: String = ""
    var currentPhoneNumber: String = ""
    var currentLatitude: String = ""
    var currentLongitude: String = ""
    var latitude21: String = ""
    var longitude21: String = ""
   
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func fetchData2() {
        let urlString = "https://map.yahooapis.jp/placeinfo/V1/get?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&appid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data, let xmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parseXML1(xmlString: xmlString)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseXML1(xmlString: String) {
        guard let data = xmlString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Failed to convert XML string to data.")
            return
        }

        let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self

        if parser.parse() {
            print("XML parsing 成功.")
            objectWillChange.send()
        } else {
            print("XML parsing エラー.")
        }
    }

    func fetchData() {
        let urlString = "https://map.yahooapis.jp/search/local/V1/localSearch?appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&gc=\(selectedCategory)&lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&sort=geno"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data, let xmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parseXML(xmlString: xmlString)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseXML(xmlString: String) {
        locations.removeAll()

        guard let data = xmlString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Failed to convert XML string to data.")
            return
        }

        let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
        parser.delegate = self

        if parser.parse() {
            print("XML parsing 成功.")
            objectWillChange.send()
        } else {
            print("XML parsing エラー.")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
            self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)

            self.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
            self.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        }
    }

    var excludedElements: Set<String> = ["Property", "Country", "Genre", "Station"]

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String: String] = [:]) {
        currentElement = elementName

        if elementName == "Feature" {
            isReadingFeatureName = true
            shouldSkip = false // <Feature>
        }

        if shouldSkip {
            return
        }

        if elementName == "Geometry" {
            shouldSkip = true
            return
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        if !trimmedString.isEmpty {
            switch currentElement {
            case "Name":
                if isReadingFeatureName && !shouldSkip {
                    currentiName = trimmedString
                }

            case "Address":
              currentAddress = trimmedString
                               locat1 = currentAddress
            case "Coordinates":
                let coordinatesComponents = trimmedString.components(separatedBy: ",")
                if coordinatesComponents.count == 2,
                    let latitude21 = Double(coordinatesComponents[0]),
                    let longitude21 = Double(coordinatesComponents[1]) {
                    currentLatitude = "\(latitude21)"
                    currentLongitude = "\(longitude21)"
                    locat25 = currentLatitude
                    locat23 = currentLongitude
                }
            case "Tel1":
                currentPhoneNumber = trimmedString
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
         if elementName == "Feature" {
             let location = LocationInfo(
                 name: currentiName,
                 address: currentAddress,
                 phoneNumber: currentPhoneNumber,
                 coordinates: "\(locat23), \(locat25)",
                 locat12: locat12,
                 locat23: locat23,
                 locat25: locat25
             )
             locations.append(location)
         }
     }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State private var isSearching = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker("Category", selection: $locationManager.selectedCategory) {
                    Text("病院").tag("0401")
                    Text("福祉施設").tag("0404")
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .frame(width: 200, alignment: .center)
                .font(.system(size: 14))

                Button(action: {
                    print("Search button pressed")
                    locationManager.fetchData()
                    locationManager.fetchData2() // Call fetchData2
                    isSearching = true
                }) {
                    Text("検索")
                }

                if isSearching {
                    List {
                        Text("現在地: \(locationManager.locat1)") // Display locat1
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                            .padding(.bottom, 20)

                        ForEach(locationManager.locations, id: \.id) { location in
                            NavigationLink(destination: LocationDetail(location: location)) {
                                LocationRow(location: location)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("位置情報")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct LocationRow: View {
    var location: LocationInfo

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(location.name)")
                .font(.headline)
            Text("\(location.address)")
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
}

struct LocationDetail: View {
    var location: LocationInfo

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(location.name)")
                .font(.headline)
            Text("住所: \(location.address)")
            Text("番号: \(location.phoneNumber)")

           
            Map(coordinateRegion: .constant(MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(location.locat23) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(location.locat25) ?? 0.0),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001)
            )))
            .frame(width: 400,height: 400)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(
                
                Marker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(location.locat23) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(location.locat25) ?? 0.0), tint: .red)
            )
        }
        .navigationTitle("詳細")
    }
}


struct Marker: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var tint: Color

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .foregroundColor(tint)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -15) //
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: 「うまく動かない」の部分をもう少し具体的に説明した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。(例えば何かエラーが出る、であればエラーメッセージヲ質問に追記してください)

Answer (score 0):

値が変わった際に、Viewにも反映させたい場合、`ObservableObject`を準拠させ、プロパティに`@Published`をつかる必要があります。

```swift
@Published var selectedCategory = "0401"
@Published var locations: [LocationInfo] = []
@Published var locat1: String = ""
```

APIキーがないので、これだけの修正で動くかはわかりません。